# Required conditions for using a t-test

Tags: normality-assumption

The conditions that I have learned are as follows:

1. If the sample size less than 15 a t-test is permissible if the sample is roughly symmetric, single peak, and has no outliers.
2. If the sample size at least 15 a t-test can be used omitting presence of outliers or strong skewness.
3. With a larger sample the t-test  can be use even if skewed distribution if the sample is greater than 30, but  less than 10% of the population.

Why can't you use a the t-test when the sample size is larger than 10% of the population size?  What happens then? Do you use the z-test?

Comment: As in the answers above, I find rule 3 to be somewhat bewildering. And I am not certain the z-test is the reason behind it. I suspect it's based on some sort of argument that there is an unusual covariance between your sample and the rest of the populations. I.e. if we already draw the samples that are far from the rest of the distribution due to the skewness, they won't be in the rest of the population anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to understand why there are two tests, for a same quantity. Let's say you have a sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$, drawn from an unknown distribution and you want to test if the mean of the distribution is zero or not.

So you compute the sample mean $\overline x = {1\over n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. And you compute the sample variance $s^2 = {1\over n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2$. And finally, you reduce $\overline x$ by the standard error $s = \sqrt{s^2}$, considering ${\overline x \over s/\sqrt n}$.

There are two cases :

- the underlying distribution is normal ; then ${\overline x \over s/\sqrt n}$ is distributed like a $t$ distribution (if the mean is zero), and you use a $t$ test. This is an **exact** procedure.
- you don’t know whether the underlying distribution is normal or not. If $n$ is big enough, the central limit theorem tells you that ${\overline x \over s/\sqrt n}$ is **approximately** distributed like a standard normal distribution (if the mean is zero), and you use a $z$ test. This is an **approximate** procedure.

What you were stating are just guidelines to help you decide if the assumptions required for $t$ test are satisfied.

I don’t get rule 3. For me, it is just false. If the distribution is skewed, it is not normal, and you have no reason to think that the $t$ test will perform better than the $z$ test.

Comment: When the distribution is skewed, the *sampling distribution* of the mean may still be (and often is) sufficiently close to Normal for the t test to apply.

Comment: The sampling distribution of the mean will be close to normal, so we can use a $z$ test. There’s no reason for the sampling distribution of the reduced mean $\overline x / s$ to be closer to the $t$ distribution than to the normal distribution. Or is there any?

Comment: This is hard to answer theoretically, because it depends on circumstance. But overall if the underlying distribution has one or more heavy tails (compared to the Normal), I would expect the t distribution to be a better approximation to the distribution of $\bar{x}/s$ than the z distribution.

Comment: In some circumstances, yes. But in others, no...

Comment: @whuber, I think you’re right. I tried with a variety of distributions, and in many cases a $t$ distribution is better than anormal distribution. Note however that with skewed distributions like an Exp(λ=0.1) both are terrible.

Comment: As a conclusion, I still think teaching the above "rule 3" is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree: I cannot conceive of any good justification for rule 3 and I can think of many exceptions. The (unpaired) t-test is notoriously sensitive to skewness and that "10% of population" threshold appears to be without foundation.

Comment: @elvis tell that to the ap statistics exam board.

Comment: I would be glad to... anyway this rule is in your course and, I suppose, nowhere else. Only your professors can tell you how they expect you to apply it. We can’t help ; just advice you that, once the exam is over, you must always keep a critical eye on the material you’ve been taught, as it can contains some mistakes. This happens, unfortunately -- even to excellent teachers.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use the t-test if you like -- it's just more conservative.  As your sample size grows larger, the Central Limit Theorem says that the distribution of your mean approaches a normal distribution, regardless of the underlying population distribution.  Therefore, you can use the Z-test, since that compares your statistic with a normal distribution.

Comment: ok, but which formula do I use to find the degrees of freedom?

Comment: There are no degrees of freedom for a Z-test.  If you are conducting a one sample t-test, you use your sample size minus one for the degrees of freedom:  n-1.

Comment: also, why can't the sample be larger than 10% of the population?

Comment: I was meaning with the t-test? there are several to choose from, which one is the best?

Comment: It can be larger than 10% of the population, it's just that in that case, you can use a z-test (as @StatsStudent said). A z-test is somewhat more powerful, although with large N, the t-test and the z-test become almost identical.  Which df formula to use depends on various conditions.

Comment: @Peter Under what conditions, precisely, is a z-test more powerful than a t-test? (I find it unlikely that such an omnibus statement would be true without significant restrictions on its scope of applicability.)

Comment: @whuber Considering that both make similar assumptions as to shape of distribution, but t-test is "wider" because of df, I'd think it was more or less generally true.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter Your comment is vague: *what,* precisely, would you think is generally true? Concerning your first clause: the t-test and z-test make subtly but markedly different assumptions about distributions. The z-test (for any statistic $w$) assumes the sampling distribution of $w$ is close to normal *with known variance,* while the t-test assumes the sampling distribution is close to normal with a variance to be estimated. A more general application is to cases where $w/\sqrt{\text{Var}(w)}$ can be shown to have an approximate Student distribution with a known DF, but this becomes tautological.

Comment: @whuber OK, how about "if the assumptions are met and you apply both a z-test and a t-test, sometimes the z-test will reject the null when the t-test fails to do so". In practice, of course, with large n, the 2 distributions are virtually identical.

Comment: We need to watch out for two things in your last statement, @Peter: (1) *which* assumptions are being met?  Those of the z-test or those of the t-test? (2) In order to make a conclusion about power, you need first to establish that these tests are achieving their nominal false positive rates. A z-test may appear to be more powerful than some other test merely because it has an inflated false positive rate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for the third rule is in its need to adhere to CLT, and therefore be nearly normal. CLT states that a sampling distribution model is relatively normal for a large sampling frame, regardless of the distribution of the population, as long as the sampled individuals are independent.

This 10% rule is to protect the independence of the sampled individuals when sampling without replacement by sampling only a small fraction of the population, assuring that any relation can be generally minimized by randomization.

If you want to see the mechanics on why this percentage is chosen, University of Texas explains it more in depth here: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/M358KInstr/TenPctCond.pdf [WHERE DOES THE 10% CONDITION COME FROM?][1],
But I sourced my general information off of "Stats, Modeling the World" 1st ed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the necessity for the comparison. T-test and Z-test I believe, operate under different conditions. T-test is Parametric, while Z-test is one of the known four nonparametric equivalent. Please somebody should correct me if my assumption wrong.